# Is it possible for users to post to my Facebook page through my site?

Tags: facebook

I have an idea for a site and I'm just trying to figure out if it's possible. Here is what I want to happen.

1. User logs into my site with Facebook.
2. User posts something to my site.
3. With user's consent, their post also appears on my Facebook page.

I've found some info about users posting to their own Facebook page through a third party, but I can't find anything about letting them post to your own Facebook page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to post on another user's wall (Facebook page) without being friends. If you are friends with that person you can use the FB.ui method:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
    caption: 'An example caption',
    from: 'USER-ID',
    to: 'FRIEND-ID'
}, function(response){});
```

For more information see [Facebook Developer Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)